# Make the difference between two strings using only loops

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, diff

Write a program that takes two strings and displays, without doubles, the
characters that appear in either one of the strings.

The display will be in the order characters appear in the command line, and
will be followed by a `\n`.

in short, I want to do something like that:

```
first string: "zpadinton"
second string: "paqefwtdjetyiytjneytjoeyjnejeyj"
```

and  output will be:

```
output: "zpadintoqefwjy"
```

other examples:

```
string1: "rien" 
string2: "cette phrase ne cache rien"
output: "rienct phas"

string1: "ddf6vewg64f"
string2: "gtwthgdwthdwfteewhrtag6h4ffdhsd"
output: "df6vewg4thras"
```

I'm trying to do something like that:

```
  char et(char *str, char *str2)
{
    int i;
    int current;
    int check;
    char tmp[strlen(*str) + strlen(*str2)];

    i = 0;
    current = 0;
    check = 0;
    while(*str)
    {
        check = 0;
        while (check != current){
            if (tmp[check] == *str)
                return (0);
            check++;
        }
        if (check == current)
        {
            printf("%c", *str);
            tmp[current] = *str;
            ++check;
        }
        str++;
    }
    while(*str2)
    {
        check = 0;
        while (check != current){
            if (tmp[check] == *str2)
                return (0);
            check++;
        }
        if (check == current)
        {
            printf("%c", *str2);
            tmp[current] = *str2;
            ++check;
        }
        str2++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

But this not working.
How I cat do this?

P.S: I want do to this without using function `strcmp` `strcpy` or `boolean type of date`, or something like that.

Comment: Did you mean `second string: "Hello"`?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: @Dumitru Srelet,...."Helllo"?......not "Hello"?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, and yes, I mean "hello" not "helllo"

Comment: What if your strings are "foo" and "bar"? What should the algorithm output?

Comment: How I can to do this?

Comment: it will output "fobar"

Comment: this is more examples:
"rien" "cette phrase ne cache rien"
will output:
rienct phas

Comment: Then the hello world example sohuld output "Wrd" instead of "World". Re-phrase the question and define "difference" strictly.

Comment: @DumitruStrelet you really should explain what _exactly_ your algorithm is supposed to display. It's hard (or even impossible) to understand that from the samples you have provided in the comments. Please edit your question and elaborate _and_ provide at least 4-5 examples.

Comment: Write a program that takes two strings and displays, without doubles, the
characters that appear in either one of the strings.

The display will be in the order characters appear in the command line, and
will be followed by a \n.

If the number of arguments is not 2, the program displays \n.

Comment: @MichaelWalz. like that?

Comment: @DumitruStrelet that's better, now put some samples at it will almost be perfect.

Comment: Also, why no boolean? Do you have to be limited with something? Anyway, you need to keep track of symbols already output, and skip the current char if it was outputted once already.

Comment: I want to this more hardcore. And I cant using more syntax than while, for etc..

Comment: Please use "@username" syntax to respond to someone, so they would be notified about your message. Can you change the input strings?

Comment: It's a subject from the school 42.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
void twodiff(char* s1,char* s2) {
    bool[256] set1; // screw mallocs
    bool[256] set2;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<256;i++) {
        set1[i]=false;
        set2[i]=false;
    }
    int l1=strlen(s1);
    int l2=strlen(s2);
    for (i=0;i<l1;i++) set1[s1[i]]=true;
    for (i=0;i<l2;i++) set2[s2[i]]=true;
    for (i=0;i<256;i++) set1[i]=set1[i]^set2[i]; // combine sets by xor
    for (i=0;i<l1;i++) {
        if (set1[s1[i]]) {
            set1[s1[i]]=false;
            printf("%c",s1[i]);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<l2;i++) {
        if (set1[s2[i]]) {
            set1[s2[i]]=false;
            printf("%c",s2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you want characters tht appear in s1 XOR s2, that is, in ONLY one OR the other string. If you need "s1 OR s2", change the combine condition.

UPDATE: Assuming you can change the passed strings, you can plain replace all symbols that you've already output by a symbol that'll be skipped in the processing. This isn't a good thing to do, but with these constraints it'll be the easiest approach.

```
void manglestr(char* s1, char* s2) {
    char mangler;
    int i;
    int j;
    int l1=strlen(s1);
    int l2=strlen(s2);
    if (0==l1) mangler=s2[0]; else mangler=s1[0];
    printf("%c",mangler);
    for (i=0;i<l1;i++) {
        if (s1[i]!=mangler) {
            printf("%c",s1[i]);
            for (j=i1+1;j<l1;j++) if (s1[j]==s1[i]) s1[j]=mangler;
            for (j=0;j<l2;j++) if (s2[j]==s1[i]) s2[j]=mangler;
        } // this will ensure we mangle all characters we send to output
    }
    for (i=0;i<l2;i++) {
        if (s2[i]!=mangler) {
            printf("%c",s2[i]);
            for (j=i1+1;j<l2;j++) if (s2[j]==s2[i]) s2[j]=mangler;
        }
    }
}
```